# Negative powers of 2 in C

Tags: c

I am trying to avoid the use of `pow` in C.

`pow(2,16)` can be written as `1<<16`, but how do I represent `pow(2,-16)`? If I do `1/(1<<16)`, I get 0.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Of course you will.. because it is integer division

Comment: so how do I do it? how do i represent pow(2, -16) or pow(2, -32) without using pow?

Comment: why do you want to avoid `pow()` ?

Comment: because I get an error message

Comment: error: more than one instance of overloaded function pow matches the arguement list

Comment: @user1838418: there's no such thing as overloaded functions in C. You're accidentally compiling your code as C++. In C++ you can avoid the ambiguity with `std::pow(2.0, -16.0)`, but first decide what language you want to write.

Comment: I'm using C syntax but compiling it using Visual C++

Comment: Checkout this example from Richard Heathfield where he translates Niklaus Wirth's program in Pascal that computes the reciprocal of a power of two to a C program:

http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c/msg/916cb8fc7dcc6e11

Comment: @user1838418: if you want to write C, use the `.c` file extension. Otherwise you will have to live with the differences between the two languages. What you're writing will be C++ that looks a bit like C, but not necessarily *actually* C since you're never showing it to a C compiler to check that it compiles as C.

Comment: I have I get that error in spite of using .c extension

Comment: Weird. But anyway, if you want to write C you should figure out what's stopping your code from being compiled as C.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the [`ldexp`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696899/functions/ldexp.html) function for floating-point powers of two, e.g. `ldexp(1, -16)`.

You can expect that this will be efficient and exploit the fact that your platform stores floating pointer numbers as mantissa plus binary exponent if applicable, so this is the moral analogue of the integral exression `1 << 16`, if you will.

Comment: One cannot expect that ldexp will be efficient. It depends on the implementation.

Answer (score 2):

A negative power denotes raising a number to a power, then inverting.

The problem you run into is fairly simple: if you start with integers, this is all going to be done with integer math, in which case there are only two possible results when you invert: 1/1 will obviously give 1. 1/(anything > 1) will give 0.

To get meaningful results, you'll generally need to convert to floating point so the fractional result can be represented: `1/(double)(1<<16)` or `1.0/(1<<16)`.

Alternatively, you can just use `pow` from the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you use floats, instead of ints:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  printf("%f %f\n", pow(2,3), pow(2,-3));

  printf("%d %f\n", (1<<3), 1.0/(1<<3));

  return 0;
}
```

result:

```
bf@bf-laptop:~/playground$ ./test
8.000000 0.125000
8 0.125000
```

Answer (score 0):

as `1/(1<<16)` all are `int` so, it typecast into integer result and hence getting as `0`.
why dont you type cast it to `float` and see the result.

```
(float)1.0/(1<<16)
```